# defining the layout of child component from parent in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue and using `Vue 2.2.1`. I am wondering if it's possible to create a reusable component that can have its layout defined by its parent. For example, consider the following pseudo code:

```
// Parent template
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <item-component :id="item.id">
        <h1><item-title /></h1>
        <p>
          <item-description />
        </p>
      </item-component>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>


// Child definition
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }
  }
  create() {
    // do some async fetch
    fetch(this.id)
      .then((result) {
        this.$data.title = result.title
        this.$data.description = result.description
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

So, the use case is that the child component is responsible for the fetching of the data by id, but the parent is responsible for laying out the data. This way, I can keep the fetch logic in one place, but reformat the data however I want in various places.

Not sure if this is possible or not. I suppose I can extract the child's fetching functionality out into a mixin, but then I'd have to create a new component for each layout variation. What is the recommended way to handle this in Vue?

Comment: Use a scoped slot. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you want the parent to include content in the child, the means to do it is via a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots). Inside, a typical slot, however, the scope is the parent's scope, meaning it does not have access to data inside the child.

In your case, you would want to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots), which is where the child is able to pass some information back to the parent to use.

```
// Parent template
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <item-component :id="item.id">
        <template scope="props">
            <h1>{{props.title}}</h1>
            <p>
              {{props.description}}
            </p>
        </template>
      </item-component>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>


// Child definition
<script>
export default {
  template:"<div><slot :title='title' :description='description'></slot></div>",
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }
  }
  create() {
    // do some async fetch
    fetch(this.id)
      .then((result) {
        this.$data.title = result.title
        this.$data.description = result.description
      })
  }
}
</script>
```